# How to debug child project process in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2019

I have a solution with two console applications. Application B is started by application A. I would like to debug both, but at least application B.

I have tried to configure as debug profile for application B to start executable A instead of itself, and I have set up application B to be the startup project. When I hit *Run* application A is started as expected, which in turn starts application B, however I still get the warning on my breakpoint in application B that it won't be hit because the source code is different. I have tried to set dependency of A from B, and also of B from A, but neither made any difference.

Update: However, attaching to the already running process B works as expected. This can be a workaround but a quite cumbersome one.

What can be done to get this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What can be done to get this right?

Please try to use the [Child Process Debugging Power Tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsdbgplat.MicrosoftChildProcessDebuggingPowerTool) which is also suitable for VS2019.

We can easily debug this child project with this extension by `Debug-->Other Debug Targets-->Child Process Debugging Settings`.(If you are debugging **.NET code**, you must choose to [enable mixed mode debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-managed-and-native-code?view=vs-2017#to-configure-mixed-mode-debugging-for-a-net-core-app) which means that you debug two different types of projects.)

In the pop-up page, check the box to open the startup child process debugging and click **Save**. After that, default debug will  support all child processes.

**Note** that by default, the same debug engine settings are used as the parent process debug.

More information you could refer to [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/introducing-the-child-process-debugging-power-tool/). Hope it could help you.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I am wondering why isn't this supported upfront by VS?

Comment: Sidenote: my VS version already has checkbox to enable native code debugging on the _Debug_ tab of the project properties editor. And this looks to be needed only for the parent process.

Comment: Hmm, glad to know it makes some help:)